# issue increasing a number only if decrease is not done first

Tags: reactjs

I am working on my first react assignment and running into a weird issue.  I need to click on text to have a form appear on the page.  While the form is displayed my size prop is 16.  If I select the - button the number will drop to 15. If I select the + it will increase back to 16.

The issue is when I try and select the + button first.  It will add a 1 to the end of my number instead of incrementing the number by 1.  It will show 161.

My HTML

```
  ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold='false'/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container'));
```

MY JS

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {hidden: 'true', size: this.props.size };

}

handleClick() {
    if(this.state.hidden == 'true') 
        this.setState({hidden: ''});
    else 
        this.setState({hidden: 'true'});

}

decrease() {
    this.setState({size: this.state.size -1});
}

increase() {
    this.setState({size: this.state.size +1});  
}

render() {

return(

       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" hidden={this.state.hidden}/>
       <button id="decreaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.decrease.bind(this)} >-</button>
       <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden={this.state.hidden}>{this.state.size}</span>
       <button id="increaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.increase.bind(this)} >+</button>
       <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >{this.props.text}
       </span>

       </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: `parseInt(number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are working with strings. try to convert it to a  `number` before you do any calculations:
`this.setState({size: Number(this.state.size) + 1});`

Comment: Awesome fixed it

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer may work, in my opinion, the real issue here is that you are passing strings to your React element when you should be passing Numbers instead.

```
<FontChooser min={4} max={40} size={16} text='Fun with React!' bold={false} />
```

Avoiding this by casting your state value to a string works, but if you're using strings for *all* your state values, you're going to run into headaches.